# virtualbox mouse integration across VMs and host

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, mouse

**What is the simple command for being able to let the mouse pointer seamlessly move between VMs and the host?**

This happened intuitively for a while, but now I cannot seem to find how to set it up.

I have `Devices > Shared Clipboard` and `Devices > Drag n Drop` both set to `bidirectional`.  But I seem to recall that there was another setting.

What else do I need to set up?

I am using VirtualBox version 4.3.28.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the VB guest additions installed on the guest as well as the settings you mention.

Comment: `Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.3.28-100309` is already installed.  What else do I need to do?  Specifically?

Comment: @CodeMed reinstall it. They update the guest addons regularly. Especially if you update VirtualBox but not the guest addons, its likely that you need to update them. Just do the procedure again to install it.

Comment: @LPChip Is there a better option besides clicking on `Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.3.28-100309`?  I already have VirtualBox running as administrator.  When I click on `Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.3.28-100309`, it opens up a new instance of VirtualBox, and the multiple instances seem to screw things up.

Comment: You simply mount the ISO as a virtual CD - it will often autorun but if not you can manually run the script.